# Is there any way to use google drive shareable link as an input to Microsoft azure form recognizer?

Tags: google-drive-api, azure-form-recognizer

**Google drive as input**

"Right now, I am using storage account as an input to form recognizer
how can I change it to google drive shareable link."

Answer (score 2):

Form Recognizer for training a custom model accepts only a storage account on Azure. When you analyze documents you can send documents via a URL, stream them or from local all options are supported. To analyze you can send a document on a google drive via a shareable link to it or stream it.